Can I Combine Visibility of Different Parented Objects into Single NLA track with the Animation of the Character?
I'm generating Animated Characters to use in Dungeon Alchemist--exported as GLB files. No problems with all of that.
DA just added functionality, which allows onscreen toggling through a list of NLA animations to get to the one you want to appear.  Again, no problem.
However, I want to be able to (if I can) have each NLA animation (within the list of 4 or 5 for a Character) contain different objects: a sword, a bow, a beer mug, a light. Doing this would allow me to simply toggle to the correct animation I want onscreen in DA, without having to go a menu, pull up the right object and drop a new Token onto the map.
In order to do this, it seems I need to have the full "action" I want displayed contained in ONE NLA strip.
I CAN animate the objects turning on and off (via the Show in Renders functionality).
What I CAN'T do is put that ON and OFF of a parented object into the Animation for the Character in a single NLA strip.
I can bake actions into one NLA but not like this, it seems. (I see a Bake "Object" Action in the Bake Animations dialogue, but I can't figure out how that might help.)
Any thoughts on how I can manage this, if it's possible?  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.
